# Pull most previous valid values of column into specific nan index, How?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, datetime, interpolation

I have a dataframe and some specific Indices(which only include some specific seasons)

```
                              A1      
2019-06-17 00:00:00          NaN
2019-06-17 00:00:01         1.20      
2019-06-17 00:01:59         1.00    
2019-06-17 00:02:29          NaN        
                         ...        
2020-06-17 23:55:01          NaN     
2020-06-17 23:58:45         1.99  
2020-06-17 23:59:59          NaN  

specific_ indices  = 
DatetimeIndex([                   
'2019-06-17 00:00:01'  ,
'2019-06-17 00:01:59'  ,
'2019-06-17 00:02:29'  ,
'2020-06-17 23:55:01'  ,
'2020-06-17 23:58:45'  ,
'2020-06-17 23:59:59'  ]
```

How can i get on this specific indices (only if its a NaN !), the previous valid value?

(like this:)

```
                              A1  
2019-06-17 00:00:00          NaN     
2019-06-17 00:00:01         1.20      
2019-06-17 00:01:59         1.00    
2019-06-17 00:02:29         1.00       
                         ...        
2020-06-17 23:55:01         1.00     
2020-06-17 23:58:45         1.99  
2020-06-17 23:59:59         1.99
```

**Note: (someone falsely marked this question as similar to another one)**

Read Carefully: I already have the specific nan indices => I only need to know how to copy the most previous VALID (==non nan) value onto this index. How to do that?

**EDIT:**

```
# when I use MrFuppes Function:
def get_last_valid(df, t, colname):
    try:
        i = np.flatnonzero(df.index == t)[0]
    except IndexError:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return df[colname].iloc[:i+1].dropna().iloc[-1]

# with this specified index to fill the NaNs of:
dti=  pd.to_datetime( pd.Index(['2019-06-17 00:02:29', '2020-06-17 23:59:59'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None) ) 

# then also the indices between the last valid and the NaN to fill
# are filled by the valid value. 
# I could save the location of the other NaNs not to fill and 
#later set them NaN again (or is there a better idea?)
                       A1
2019-06-17 00:00:00   NaN
2019-06-17 00:00:01  1.20
2019-06-17 00:01:59  1.01 # <== should be NaN
2019-06-17 00:02:29  1.01
2020-06-17 23:55:01   NaN
2020-06-17 23:58:45  1.99
2020-06-17 23:59:59  1.99
```

But most importantly: is there a vectorised approach to this? (because of time efficiency)

Comment: Filter the dataset with only not nan and then iloc[-1]

Comment: @LaurentR so you mean for each specific NaN, finding its possible location in df.dropna() and then going 1 index back. Isnt there a more efficient way? (because im working with millions of rows)

Comment: It seems I didn't really get what you want to do ^^ Do you want to manipulate the data source, I mean column 'A1' in the example?

Comment: @MrFuppes You got it to a high degree, i guess^^. Is there a way to vectorize this function? (because i need to manipulate millions of rows)

Comment: @Iroquois_Pliskin: I've edited my answer how you can manipulate the column in-place. Right now, I'm not sure how this can be vectorized; but you're right, that would be better in performance-terms...

Answer (score 1):

An option might be to get the index of each timestamp in the DatetimeIndex, select part of the column based on that index, and get the last non-NaN value by using `.dropna().iloc[-1]` as @LaurentR suggested in the comment section. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# df
#                        A1
# 2019-06-17 00:00:00   NaN
# 2019-06-17 00:00:01  1.20
# 2019-06-17 00:01:59  1.00
# 2019-06-17 00:02:29   NaN
# 2020-06-17 23:55:01   NaN
# 2020-06-17 23:58:45  1.99
# 2020-06-17 23:59:59   NaN

# dti
# DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-17 00:01:59', '2020-06-17 23:59:59'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

def get_last_valid(df, t, colname):
    try:
        i = np.flatnonzero(df.index == t)[0]
    except IndexError:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return df[colname].iloc[:i+1].dropna().iloc[-1]
    
for t in dti:
    print(t.isoformat(), get_last_valid(df, t, 'A1'))

# 2019-06-17T00:01:59 1.0
# 2020-06-17T23:59:59 1.99
```

---

If you're sure all of the entries from the DatetimeIndex exist in the dataframe's index, you can achieve the same with

```
for t in dti:
    df.loc[df.index == t, 'A1'] = df['A1'].iloc[:(df.index == t).nonzero()[0][0]+1].dropna().iloc[-1]
```

Note: this also modifies column 'A1' on the fly.

Comment: could you explain what each part in the func does? (those 3:  " try:"    "except IndexError:"  "else:") because its somehow hard for me to get it.

Comment: @Iroquois_Pliskin: I put the `try/except` there because I wasn't sure if all the elements from your `DatetimeIndex` also appear in the index of your `df`. `i = np.flatnonzero(df.index == t)[0]` retrieves the index of a specific element `t`. If that fails (element is not there), the function just returns `np.nan`. Else, it returns the first element (`.iloc[-1]`) that is not NaN (`.dropna()`) from the selected column.

Comment: so when im sure that the specified_index is in dataframe i can leave the try/ except and just do a:                                                                                                     def get_last_valid(df, t, colname):
        return df[colname].iloc[:i+1].dropna().iloc[-1]   ?

Comment: + problem: if the index that needs to be filled has another NaN in  between, the this value is also filled :( I guess I could safe the location of the other nans and set them nan again after (is there a better idea?)              (see edit in question)                                                   Otherwise:  Is there maybe a vectorised approach to this get_last_valid(...)?